# Is there a way to use a href in Text Edit to other documents?

Tags: html, hyperlink, href, textedit

I started using TextEdit for writing html, and when I try to use a href to link to other documents, it says "No webpage was found for the web address: file:///Users/user/Documents/â€œfile:///Users/user/Documents/helloWorld.htmlâ€". the document I am linking to is called helloWorld, so I am pretty sure it is not a typo. What can I do to fix the error?
Here is the code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>About Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>About hello World</p>
<a href=‘file:///Users/user/Documents/helloWorld.html'>Home</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you share how you created the `href` link? You could try replacing the double quotes after the `=` with single quotes.  Double quotes and curvy-quotes look very similar but are not the same and can give HTML problems sometimes (that's my non-technical description of the issue)

Comment: You got a typo mistake in your href segment you are using a `\`` instead of a `'`

Comment: You have a user called `user` on your system? If you dont, then unless your url uses `user` as a place-holder, it's never going to work. You're much better off using `relative-urls` - I.e put the target file in the same folder as the code shown above and then remove all of the path, leaving just the filename. To access a target in the parent directory of the initial file, use `../` before the filename.

Comment: Why don't you use a browser to view the target html file manually, then copy the URL shown into the `href` attribute?

Comment: @Onilol - You were both right: I had a typo after the '='. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Give it a try by spesifying the whole path to the other file, such as

```
<a href="file:///C:/Users/user/Documents/helloWorld.html">
```

Or if it was in your F drive then

```
<a href="file:///F:/Users/user/Documents/helloWorld.html">
```

However keep in mind, if you are going to be sharing this page with other people of course they are most probably not going to have access to the same file path as you. So the file will not be displayed.

Comment: This didn't work, But it removed the problem of â€'s and the repetition of the file name in the error screen.

Comment: Also make sure you are using the correct characters after the href '='

Comment: You and Onilol were both right. It was a typo! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Mac, you could run terminal, find the file you want to link to, and drag it to terminal. It will show the directory of the file and you could copy&paste it to the href tag.